# "Resources monitoring" vs "Monitoring of resources"

Tags: phrase-usage

Please help me understand a difference between phrases "resources monitoring" vs "monitoring of resources", "characteristics of devices" vs "devices characteristics" and the like.

Comment: It should be noted that the difference is small, and in most contexts you can use either.  Because of this, you'll sometimes see people jokingly swap around other words or phrases, like "book of faces" for Facebook, because the meaning is still clear.

Comment: @PlutoThePlanet There are pitfalls, though.